# Get data from sql to datagridview while looping?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I was trying to do that when I open a file from Excel and display it in a `dt_data`, I want to select if the particular columns in `dt_data` is existing in the database and display the results in another `datagridview` which is `dt_sample`.

I've got it working but the problem is only the first row from `dt_data` is displaying.

```
Try

       For i As Integer = 0 To dt_data.RowCount - 3
               Dim meter_number As String
               meter_number = dt_data.Rows(i).Cells(3).Value
               Dim query As String = "Select * from customer where meter_num = @meter_num"
               conn.Open()
               Dim command As New SqlCommand(query, conn)
               command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@meter_num", meter_number)
               Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
               Dim ds As New DataSet
               da.Fill(ds, "customer")
               dt_sample.DataSource = ds.Tables(i)

               conn.Close()

           Next
       Catch ex As SqlException
           MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "SQL Error")
       Catch ex As Exception
           MsgBox(ex.Message, MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "General Error")
           'End Try
           'Catch ex As Exception
           'MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Error: {0}", ex.Message), "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
       End Try
```

Comment: I'm afraid that that's a terrible explanation.  Are you saying that you are retrieving a bunch of `meter_num` values from an Excel file and you want to display all records from the `customer` table that contain any of those values?

Comment: Your current code can't possibly work, regardless of what you're trying to achieve, because you keep setting the `DataSource` of the grid (?) repeatedly, so you're only ever going to see the last set of values.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/8czgIos.png

Comment: @jmcilhinney how should i do it?

Comment: Do what?  I asked you a question but you haven't answered it.  I said that your initial explanation was poor but you haven't tried to improve it.

Comment: @jmcilhinney regarding to your question, yes i want to retrieve those values for me to compare it

Comment: You should only be executing a single query to get all the second-stage data.  Perform the first query and get all the values, then insert all those values into your second query in an `IN` clause, e.g. `SELECT * FROM customer WHERE meter_num IN (1, 2, 3)`.  If the values are all numbers then it's safe to insert the values directly.  Otherwise, use parameters like [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?503298).